# Sharepoint Designer Workflow to add file using REST api with some content in the file

Tags: rest, designer-workflow, file-upload

I am creating a SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 where I add a file using REST api call. File gets added perfectly, however it goes empty. I want some content in that file, let's say "Test File Content".

```
<Site URL>_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Document Library')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
```

Do I have to add something in the headers to have some content in that file?
Please, do let me know if you have any suggestions.